# Weird result in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

`SELECT COUNT(1), name, (@i := @i + 1) AS counter FROM mytbl, (SELECT @i := 0) tmp_tbl GROUP BY counter`

For this query, the counter column increases its value with 2.

But if I remove COUNT(1), such as:

`SELECT name, (@i := @i + 1) AS counter FROM mytbl, (SELECT @i := 0) tmp_tbl GROUP BY counter`

counter column increases its value with 1.

Can anyone explain why this behavior?

---

Table would be:
`create table mytbl (name VARCHAR(20));`

With data:

`INSERT INTO mytbl VALUES
('a1'),
('a2'),
('a3');`

Comment: Without any sample data that would help us reproduce the issue you mention it is really hard to examine the problem.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Please see the edit. :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [MySQL document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html), we should not assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement. We might get the expected results, but this is not guaranteed. Changing the statement (for example, by adding a GROUP BY, HAVING, or ORDER BY clause) may cause MySQL to select an execution plan with a different order of evaluation.

In your query, *counter* field will be evaluated in SELECT statement and then be used in GROUP BY statement. Seem when we add an aggregation function to SELECT statement, the field that be used in GROUP BY statement will be evaluated 2 times.

I've create a [demo](http://rextester.com/OGIV53676), you could check it. In the demo, I've this query

```
SELECT Count(1), 
       name, 
       ( @i := @i + 1 ) AS counter, 
       ( @j := @j + 1 ) AS group_field 
FROM   (SELECT 'A' AS name 
        UNION 
        SELECT 'B' AS name 
        UNION 
        SELECT 'C' AS name) mytable, 
       (SELECT @i := 0) tmp_tbl, 
       (SELECT @j := 0) tmp_tbl1 
GROUP  BY group_field;
```

In the execution result, *counter* field only be increased by 1 and *group_field* be increased by 2.

To make the counter field only increasing by 1, you could try this

```
SELECT Count(1), 
       name, 
       counter 
FROM   (SELECT name, 
               ( @i := @i + 1 ) AS counter 
        FROM   mytbl, 
               (SELECT @i := 0) tmp_tbl) data 
GROUP  BY counter;
```